# Analytics ignoring advertising features setting

Tags: google-analytics, advertising

I've been having trouble with my `Demographics` reports in my Google Analytics account that I administer. After I log in, I expand the `Audience` tab, then `Demographics`, and then select `Age`. There is a note that says:

```
Some data in this report may have been removed when a threshold was applied. Learn more
```

Clicking `learn more` informs me about the data threshold that is applied in order to prevent showing personally identifiable information. I am aware of the threshold and it hadn't been a problem in the past as the number of users on my site are well beyond that threshold. When I expand the date range for a year instead of the default month, I see that I was collecting demographic data earlier, but for some reason it all stopped on November 10, 2014; it dropped to zero. I did not change anything with the analytics tracking code around that time.

To complicate the situation, I recently noticed a notification in the top right that says my `Advertising Features` setting is turned off. The problem is... it's not. I have clicked the link that says `check again` and waited a day, but I am still receiving the notification. Any ideas why Google is ignoring this setting and not collecting data?

The alert:

[image]

My settings:

[image]

Comment: I can verify that Google isn't ignoring this across the board - I manage a number of client Analytics accounts and none of them have this issue. Have you double-checked your code hasn't mistakenly been swapped over for an older version that didn't include the display features snippet? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en

Comment: @FarhadD I am using the latest `Universal Analytics` code, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Universal Analytics code alone isn't enough. You need to either set the Advertising Features in your settings or in your code itself. Have you gone into the Admin Property settings and enabled this, as explained in the link i shared in my comment above?

Comment: Yes, I have a picture in my post illustrating this. That is the setting in my own profile turned on.

Comment: Sorry - the image didn't load previously. I see it now. Interesting! At this point I'd do one of 2 things: 1st choice, call Google AdWords support and ask them to troubleshoot it - there are times when the notifications aren't spot on and we've been told to ignore them. 2nd choice, also update the tracking code to enable Advertising Features & Reports